# Safariviewcontroller reloads content when open another app then return

Tags: ios, objective-c, reload, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am trying to implement an SSO scenario with using `sfsafariviewcontroller`. The scenario is below.

1. The user opens the app, and the login page displays in `wkwebview`.
2. User clicks login button then `safariviewcontroller` opens the SSO page.
3. The user enters username and password then presses login button in SSO page.
4. For two-step verification, the user enters an SMS-pin in next SSO page and presses the **Done** button.
5. When verification completes, the user automatically returns with authorized state.

The problem is at step 4. When the user opens messages to get the SMS-pin and returns to the app, the `sfsafariviewcontroller` reloads the page with the initial URL. So the user cannot enter the SMS-pin.

Why does `SfSafariViewController` reload the page with the initial URL every time?

The implementation is below.

```
@interface WebContentViewController()<SFSafariViewControllerDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation WebContentViewController

...
...

- (BOOL)decideNavigationFlow:(NSURL *) url isLinkClicked: (BOOL) isLinkClicked {
....
....
 if(IS_IOS9_OR_GREATER){
            SFSafariViewController *svc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
         [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
}

-(void)safariViewController:(SFSafariViewController *)controller didCompleteInitialLoad:(BOOL)didLoadSuccessfully {
    LogInfo(@"#######Initial load completed");
}

-(void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller {
    LogInfo(@"#######Done pressed");
}
@end
```

Comment: having the same issue, commenting so I can return with the answer at some point.